# Bad approximation by fractions with quadratic denominators

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Are there irrational numbers $\alpha$ satisfaying that

> $$ \left|\alpha-\frac{m}{k^2}\right| \geq \frac{\varepsilon}{k^2} \text{ for some } \varepsilon>0 \text{ and all } k\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1},m \in \mathbb{Z}?$$

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the direction of the inequality. May I ask from where it question is taken? A book reference would be great

Comment: The question is not taken from a book and unfortunately I don't know references concerning such questions.

Comment: You can post an answer to your question and accept it so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a suitable reference. The answer to my question is "No", see [here](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article/os-19/1/249/1613069).